# Unable to show image in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, sitefinity

I am facing an issue since 2 days, I have a user control which simply has  I have Images saved in my project. I have provided proper path to it and still it is not showing that image. I used Chrome's developer's tool to inspect the issue and it give me

```
src="/images/Uploads/home_banner1.jpg"
```

when I right clicked on scr and opened link in new tab, url looked like  localhost/images/Uploads/home_banner1.jpg that means it is trying to find image in root's images/.... folder, right? I am sure I have an image there with the same name but still webpage says,"The resource cannot be found." means 404 error. I removed image name from url and pressed enter and it shows all files in that folder, even after clicking file under directory it still give 404 error, what is this, how to solve, did any one came across it? I ahve lot of questions in my mind, please help me solve this.

**EDIT**

I have solved it ('compromised' would be better word rather 'solved'). I placed same images in different folder and its running fine, It was never an issue with security of that folder means problem must be something else. I know it is tedious to rectify this but still if someone faced and rectified the same, you could share how you did so. I am getting more curious to find out why changing folder did work for me?

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you try to write this: src="~/images/Uploads/home_banner1.jpg"

Comment: actually ImageUrl is set in code behind and as I said in question **It is showing proper path when opened in new tab**

Comment: What webserver software are you using? IIS?

Comment: Thanks for paying attention, Yes, IIS

Comment: @Imad: Just so you know, this question is very specific to your setup, it is not something that any one of us can easily replicate. This is the reason why it is not getting much attention. From your explanation you are saying that the image is actually there, in that exact path, so it isn't easy to answer why it isn't showing. You need to provide enough information as possible, so we can replicate the issue, or at the very least a link so we can see the problem in action. I fear this could by one of those issues you will only fix by a lot of digging and debugging by yourself

Comment: hmmm... it will be a fight for me to get it resolved.

Comment: It shouldn't be a fight - it's an image loading, so it'll either load or not, but your question isn't getting any attention because it looks like a simple case of an image not loading which is about the easiest thing to debug.  BUT like musefan pointed out, it's something specific to your project and configuration.  Can you post the code for the control? When you click on the filename after seeing the directory list, what happens?  Do you get a real 404 error or is it a corrupt image or something?  Is there any special image handling or URL rewriting in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Open `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`, find your website/virtual directory, choose `Content View` from the bottom of the window, find the image that doesn't show, right click on it and choose `Browse`.

IE should open with the image displayed on the page and the **correct URL** for it on the URL bar.

Voila. :)

If you cannot get the image to show, then you may be experiencing a number of problems with your IIS setup or metabase or .net version.

Check the above 1st and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I recreate the scenario as you explained and it seems to be working as it was expected...
Following is the user control...

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<img src="images/uploads/home_banner1.jpg" />
```

and below is the page...

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" id="WebUserControl1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

just compare with your html what is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using an Image control:

```
<asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageURL="~/Uploads/home_banner1.jpg" />
```